# Node Sequelize filter by array on column based on array input

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to do a wildcard search on one of the DB columns. The input params are passed as an array of string.
Example:

```
{ name: ['John','Doe'] }
```

Need to return (id: 1, id:2) as first element matches id:1 and second element matches id: 2. How to effectively use like statement.

```
|  name (string)         | id | 
|------------------------|----|
| John,steve             |  1 |   
| clive,steve,Doe        |  2 |    
| suzan                  |  3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your best option will be to use the [regexp operator](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#:%7E:text=OR%20authorId%20%3D%2013%3B-,Operators,-Sequelize%20provides%20several) in the sql query.

The raw SQL would look something like:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE name REGEXP 'John|Doe';
```

In Sequelize, your model query might looks something like:

```js
someModel.findAll({
  where: {
    name: {
      [Op.regexp]: 'John|Doe',
    },
  },
  attributes: ['id'],
})
```

I imagine that the list of names to check for would be dynamic so just replace the value assigned to the regex operator above to a string you've built.

```js
const names = ['John', 'Doe'];
const nameRegexStr = names.join('|');
```